# Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they where created?

Tags: java, android, realm

In Realm, I am using `executeTransactionasync` method and in execute I am calling a method from utility class but when I am calling this method I am getting an error

> Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they where created

**Utils.class**

```
public void update_data(final Realm realm) {
    data bgTran = realm.where(data.class).equalTo("obj", "hello").findFirst();
    if(bgTran!= null){
        bgTran.settime("7 June");
    }
}
```

**Activity Class Code**

```
realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
    @Override
    public void execute(final Realm bgRealm) {
        utils.update_data(realm);
    }
}, new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess() {

    }

}, new Realm.Transaction.OnError() {
    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable error) {
        //gettting Error Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they where created
    }
});
```

Can anyone please tell me as the same realm is getting passed over the method call why is in UI thread then why am I getting the error.

But When I am writing whole `executetransactionasync` in Util class then it is running perfectly fine.

**Utils.class**

```
public void update_data(final Realm realm) {
     realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
         @Override
         public void execute(final Realm bgRealm) {
             data bgTran = bgRealm.where(data.class).equalTo("obj", "hello").findFirst();
             if(bgTran!= null){
                  bgTran.settime("7 June");
             }
         }
     }, new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess() {
         @Override
         public void onSuccess() {

         }

     }, new Realm.Transaction.OnError() {
         @Override
         public void onError(Throwable error) {

         }
     });
}
```

**Edit** - The question is different from the marked question because there I know onpostExecute(UI Thread), doInBackground(Background Thread) they both access different Threads but the thing here is that as my code is in Activity Class so it will have a looper, so when I will call a method in util class now this class also can access to the looper because I am still in UI Thread then why this error is coming, **Also if this error is coming then it should also come for the second case which I have mentioned but it is not** ?

Also, how can I write a common logic like I wrote in `update_data()` and use it anywhere? Because otherwise, I would have to write the same code again and again in the every Realm `executeTransactionasync` ?

Comment: Is the actual code where you actually  get the exception `.equalTo("obj", "hello")`? Because that seems unlikely, and I'm pretty sure the answer lies in an omitted detail. Even the full stack trace is helpful.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I have only changed naming otherwise, all code is same.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce are there? Can you please help me :)

Comment: The code posted here shouldn't throw the exception, but that also means that the error is in a detail that is omitted. I stand by that.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Do you want me to show the whole log for the error?

Comment: sure that would help, you *can* remove app-specific packages tho

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Ok wait and thanks really for helping me, really appreciate your effort :)

Comment: @EpicPandaForce It was all my Mistake actually I was passing `realm` instance to `update_data`, not the `bgRealm`. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Oh man, it was all there: `utils.update_data(realm);` -___- I'm disappointed in my eyes, sorry about that

Comment: Haha, you must not I must be,  because I am the one who wrote that code :(